# YouTube API Favorites Count - PHP

Tags: youtube

I am getting youtube video data using the following url

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cognizant/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&start-index=1

but using this, the favorites count is coming as zero (0).

So now i am trying to get the favorites count using oAuth2 google-api-client youtube service. Even though its retuning the favorites count as zero.

I created project on gmail account by enabling the youtube serveice then created client id, redirect url and all.

Can you please guide me how to get the correct favorites count of an video.

Thanks and Regards
Surekha Matte

Comment: Are you sure favorite count is not zero? Because, judging by the view counts it wouldn't be surprising if no one favorited those videos.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, YouTube disabled favorite count in the API a few months ago, or maybe even a year. It hasn't been working for quite some time in my own experience, at least.